# Hint for Proving sequence $x: \Bbb N \rightarrow F$ bounded if and only if $\{x(i) \in X \mid i \in \Bbb N\}$ is.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

**Claim**

sequence $x: \Bbb N \rightarrow F$ in ordered field $F$ is bounded **if and only if** $\{x(i) \in X \mid i \in \Bbb N\}$ is bounded above and below.

**Question**

Any Hint or advice to prove above claim?

Comment: Isn't this by definition?

Comment: It looks so,but my textbook to require to prove it

Comment: Can you also write down your textbook's definition of when a sequence is bounded?

Comment: ...and your textbook's definition of when a set is bounded (above and below).

Comment: A general hint for * is to start of by knowing exactly what you're about to do. You have to make sure you understand the question first which includes the definitions that are in use. In this case it seem that it should follow quite directly from the definitions...